# How to add a blog entry to a tag in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I can assign posts(blog entries) to a  specific category in wordpress but I don't know how to do the same thing for tags. Can someone please show me the way ??

Comment: what theme are you using?

Comment: I am using Ocean wp theme

Comment: what version of WP?

Comment: I am using Wordpress 5.5.1

Comment: are you able to see the tags menus in wp-admin on the left menu or the right gutenberg document menu?

Comment: Yes I am not trying to add tags to post I want to add post to tag

Comment: Im confused,  its pretty much the same as `categories`.  Do you have an example of how you can do this with categories and can not with tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two ways through Quick Edit or Edit.

[image]

When you click Quick Edit it's on the right side here:

[image]

When you click Edit it's also on the right side, in the Document block, right beneath Category:

[image]

Does that answer your question?